# the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String

Tags: java, arrays, string, expression, field

I don't know what's happening with my code. I can't seem to figure out why an array is giving me this error. The line is `String line[] = aryLines[];` specifically `aryLines[];`

My Code:

```
public void interpretGpl(String aryLines){

    System.out.println("Interpreting");
    String line[] = aryLines[];
    String tempString[] = null;
    int tempInt[] = null;
    int i = interCount;
    boolean isInt;
    boolean storeValue = false;
```

Comment: aryLines is passed into interpretGpl with interpretGpl(aryLines[i]); as that variable was an array.

Comment: Consider editing your answer into a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), we don't know what you're trying to accomplish here and your code snippet is too limited to make much sense out of it.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `aryLines` is a String that contains lines of text separated by linefeeds. Here's the code you need for that:

```
public void interpretGpl(String aryLines) {
    String line[] = aryLines.split("\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you even trying to do here? Do you want `line` to be an array with only the string `aryLines` in it? In that case:

```
String line[] = {aryLines};
```

is what you need to do.

```
aryLines[]
```

by itself kind of means nothing. `[]` is used only in conjunction with datatypes to represent an array of that datatype. `aryLines` isn't a datatype, it is the *data*.

Answer (score 1):

`aryLines` is declared as a String.  It is not an array.  Contrariwise, `line` is an array.  It is not a String.  The thing on the right side of the = operator has to be assignable to the thing on the left side of the = operator, and Strings and arrays are completely different things.

It could be that you've chosen the wrong type for one of these variables and you wanted them to both be Strings, or both be arrays of Strings.

If the types are correct, you'll have to figure out what you wanted `aryLines[]` to do, and how to do it.